# Is "how much ever" grammatically correct?

Tags: idioms

Is the phrase *how much ever* grammatically correct?

Comment: Can you give a longer or another sentence? (to give more context) How is this phrase being used?

Answer (score 6):

I can't think of a use for "how much ever" in any unstrained construction. What I would use is "however much" (note that "however" is one word).

> However much you may wish to win the lottery, your odds of actually doing so are vanishingly small.

Comment: In first sentence, do you mean "how ever much", or "how much ever"?  Other than in your answer I don't see any refs to latter.

Comment: @jwpat7: The original question was drastically changed months later by an overzealous editor grinding for a badge. I've rolled it back so that at least the answer makes sense.